# Meteor:Can't start idle monitor until synced to server

Tags: meteor

I am using [meteor-user-status](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status)  to track the online status of users.

To track the idle status of users it seems, according to the documentation, I only need to put the following code to `Meteor.startup` on the client.

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  UserStatus.startMonitor({
       threshold: 30000,
       interval: 1000,
       idleOnBlur: true
  });
});
```

But doing so I get the error message **Can't start idle monitor until synced to server** Unfortunately I could not find out how to start the timesync. Reading the doc at github I would assume that it is started be default.

What is missing link to get the idle monitoring running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you can't start the monitor under the client is synced with the serve, so you need to wrap the [try/catchs](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp) inside a [Tracker.autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun)

```
Tracker.autorun(function () {
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
        try {
            UserStatus.startMonitor({
            threshold: 30000,
            interval: 1000,
            idleOnBlur: true
            });
        } catch(err) {
           console.log(err);
        }
    } else {
        UserStatus.stopMonitor();
    }
});
```

This should work.

Also there is a function named `UserStatus.isMonitoring()` but based o this [#33](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status/issues/33) issue seems like it can freeze the browser.

Comment: Where do I need to put the Tracker.autorun... ?

Comment: put it on the client side

Comment: thx! I initially put it in the start up this does not work, but outside  the startup all is fine

Comment: Thanks for saying this, wish we could have it in the offical answer. THere goes half a day..